# break for loop in Python

Tags: c++, python, loops, for-loop

is it possible to break a **for** loop in Python, without **break** command?
I'm asking this question in order to compare it with C++ for loop, in which actually **checks a condition** each time.

i.e. it's possible to break a for loop in C++ like below:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    i = 1000; // equal to break;
```

is it possible to do the same in Python?

```
for i in range(0,100):
    i = 10000 // not working
```

Comment: Python's `for` is more like C++11's range-based `for`, _not at all_ like the original C++ `for`. It iterates over a set of items.

Comment: What tutorial are you using to learn Python?

Comment: `i = 1000; // equal to break;` Please be kind to your fellow programmers and don't do this. If you want to break, `break`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's `for` is really a "for each" and is used with [iterables](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable), not loop conditions.

Instead, use a `while` statement, which checks the loop condition on each pass:

```py
i = 0
while i < 1000:
    i = 1000
```

Or use an `if` statement paired with a `break` statement to exit the loop:

```py
for i in range(1000):
    if i == 10:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `while` loop for that purpose:

```
i = 0
while i < 100:
    i = 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `for` doesn't work like that in Python. `for` iterates over a list (in this case) or other container or iterable. `for i in range(0, 100)` doesn't mean "increment `i` until `i` is greater than or equal to 100", it means "set `i` to successive items from a list of these 100 items until the list is exhausted."

If `i` is 50, then the next item of the list is still 51, regardless of what you may set `i` to.

`break` is better anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work (as you've noticed). The reason is that, in principle, you are iterating the elements of a list of ascending numbers (whether that is really true depends on if you're using python 2 or 3). You can use the 'break' keyword to break out of a loop at any time, although using it in excess might make it hard to follow your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might have to settle for the break statement:

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html

```
for i in range(0,100):
    print i
    if i == 10:
        break
```